# Undefined Symbol ___gxx_personality_v0 on link

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I've been getting this undefined symbol building with this command line:

```
$ gcc test.cpp
Undefined symbols:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
  etc...
```

test.cpp is simple and should build fine.  What is the deal?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use

```
g++ test.cpp
```

instead, since this is c++ code.

---

Or, if you *really* want to use `gcc`, add `-lstdc++` to the command line, like so:

```
gcc test.cpp -lstdc++
```

Running `md5` against the `a.out` produced under each scenario shows that it's the same output.

But, yeah, `g++` probably makes your world a simpler place.

Comment: I though gcc was the front end that recognized cpp files and passed it through to the correct compiler.

Comment: @Pax Diablo: Yes, it uses the correct _compiler_, however, g++ passes libstdc++ to the linker whereas gcc doesn't. :-P

Comment: Right, it's a linker problem, not a compilation one.  I normally don't build individual files from the command line like this, so I didn't even think and just typed gcc thinking it would work.

Comment: I've made that same mistake myself, at least twice that I can remember. :-)

Comment: This is not necessarily weariness or dumbness. I see lots of people answering to use g++ instead of gcc, but this is bad answer. The people asking and searching may not have that choice. I am working with libraries that have C and C++ versions, and I am writing a C program. Linking to some of these libraries made me have to link to stdc++, and I even had to specify with -L where to find it inside /usr/lib/gcc.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with dividebyzero, combining C++ and C is not unheard of. Maybe your the dumb one.

Comment: Works to compile PHP 5.3+fpm with `EXTRA_CFLAGS = -lstdc++` in Makefile

Answer (score 5):

The `.cpp` extension causes `gcc` to compile your file as a C++ file. (See the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-file-name-suffix-71).)

Try compiling the same file, but rename it to have a `.c` extension:

```
mv test.cpp
gcc test.c
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly specify the language by passing `-x c` to the compiler:

```
gcc -x c -c test.cpp -o test.o
```

---

If you run `nm test.o` on these C-language versions, you'll notice that `___gxx_personality_v0` is not listed as a symbol.
(And if you run the same command on an object file generated with `gcc -c test.cpp -o test.o`, the `___gxx_personality_v0` symbol is present.)

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone has the same problem as me: The file extension should be a `.c` not a `.C` (gcc is case-sensitive).

Comment: This is because .C files are recognized by cpp. That's the same in CMake for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, but a different solution:

C++ code in static library getting linked, and being referenced by a .m file.  Renaming the .m file to .mm fixed the issue.