# Link error "undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'" and g++

Tags: c++, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Undefined Symbol ___gxx_personality_v0 on link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203548/undefined-symbol-gxx-personality-v0-on-link)

I have a problem with the following program.

```
// fkt.cpp

#include "fkt.h"

int add2(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

And the header:

```
// fkt.h

int add2(int a, int b);
```

Now I compile this with:

```
g++ -c fkt.cpp
```

Now I run `nm` and get:

```
00000000 T _Z6add2ii
         U __gxx_personality_v0
```

When I want to use the function anywhere I get:

```
(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

How can I solve this problem? (I'm using [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) Linux.)

Comment: Can we see the command line you're using to link with? (You should be using `g++` to do the linking too if you're not already.)

Comment: Have you tried `g++ ftk.cpp -o ftk` ?

Comment: i dot the linking with ghc (using FFI)

Comment: I had this error when I forgot to change the `gcc` to `g++` in the Makefile....LOL ;)

Comment: what do you mean by "use this function" are you switching to gcc in that case?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If `g++` still gives error Try using:

```
g++ file.c -lstdc++
```

Look at this post: [What is __gxx_personality_v0 for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for)

Make sure `-lstdc++` is at the end of the command.  If you place it at the beginning (i.e. before file.c), you still can get this same error.

Comment: I have no idea what that -lstdc++ is but it helped me to compile .so library for my jni project. Thanks

Comment: It links the cpp standard library.

Comment: Was he sure he was calling g++ and not gcc? -- he shouldnt have to add -lstdc++ manually.

Answer (score 74):

It sounds like you're trying to link with your resulting object file with `gcc` instead of `g++`:

> Note that programs using C++ object
>   files must always be linked with g++,
>   in order to supply the appropriate C++
>   libraries. Attempting to link a C++
>   object file with the C compiler gcc
>   will cause "undefined reference"
>   errors for C++ standard library
>   functions:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c hello.cc
$ gcc hello.o       (should use g++)
hello.o: In function `main':
hello.o(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `std::cout'
.....
hello.o(.eh_frame+0x11):
  undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

Source: *[An Introduction to GCC - for the GNU compilers gcc and g++](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_54.html)*

Comment: Happened to me when using [distcc](https://github.com/distcc/distcc/blob/master/README.md), because it defaults to using gcc, not g++. Solution is to specify the compiler `distcc g++ [...]`

Comment: adding -fno-threadsafe-statics solved the problem for me, when using a Arduino Sketch.