# Undefined reference to _Unwind_Resume and __gxx_personality_v0

Tags: c++, exception, mingw

I'm trying to use the JsonCpp library. I'm on Windows, using MinGW and CodeBlocks.

When I include anything from the json headers, my linker implodes and gives out this two errors. I've started to look around and I found these two other questions which basically describe my problem:

[problem with g++ and "undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6045809/1356926)

[What is __gxx_personality_v0 for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/329059/1356926)

And if I declare the two missing variables as void pointers, like below, the problem goes away:

```
void * __gxx_personality_v0=0;
void * _Unwind_Resume =0;
```

However, I don't understand why this error happens. CodeBlocks is set up so that it uses migw32-g++ for cpp files, and also adding the -lstdc++ option does not fix the problem. Neither does the option -fno-exception ( I want exceptions, mind you, I was just trying ).

I'm also including a boost library in the same file and that does not cause any problems.

EDIT:

The error output is exactly what I said in my title: I get a total of 22 undefined references to _Unwind_Resume and __gxx_personality_v0 during the linking. My code is:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <include/json/value.h>
//void * __gxx_personality_v0=0;
//void * _Unwind_Resume =0;
int main () {
    std::string str1("Hello world!");
    boost::to_upper(str1);
    Json::Value k;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is there only when I include/use the JsonCPP library. Uncommenting the commented lines fixes the problem.

The command line output is this:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g  -DSFML_DYNAMIC   -IC:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\boost_1_49 -IC:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\jsoncpp-src-0.5.0 -IC:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\SFML-1.6\include -IC:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\hge181\include  -c C:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\jsoncpp-src-0.5.0 -LC:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\SFML-1.6\lib -LC:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\hge181\lib  -o bin\Debug\test.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -fno-exceptions -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system  C:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\jsoncpp-src-0.5.0\libs\mingw\libjson_mingw_libmt.a C:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\hge181\lib\gcc\libhge.a C:\Users\Svalorzen\Documents\Projects\hge181\lib\gcc\libhelp.a 
Output size is 1.22 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 3 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

SECOND EDIT:
I'm adding the command lines I use to compile the library:

```
g++ -o buildscons\mingw\src\lib_json\json_reader.o -c -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_MT -Iinclude src\lib_json\json_reader.cpp
g++ -o buildscons\mingw\src\lib_json\json_value.o -c -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_MT -Iinclude src\lib_json\json_value.cpp
g++ -o buildscons\mingw\src\lib_json\json_writer.o -c -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_MT -Iinclude src\lib_json\json_writer.cpp
ar rc buildscons\mingw\src\lib_json\libjson_mingw_libmt.a buildscons\mingw\src\lib_json\json_reader.o buildscons\mingw\src\lib_json\json_value.o buildscons\mingw\src\lib_json\json_writer.o
ranlib buildscons\mingw\src\lib_json\libjson_mingw_libmt.a
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It may help to show the actual error output.

Comment: Do you have the compiler output? What are the compiler and linker command lines?

Comment: Are you linking with `gcc` or `g++`? Note that your fix will cause null dereference and a nasty crash at runtime when an exception is thrown.

Comment: @jpalecek I've added the command line output, I hope it helps - some arguments ( hge, sfml ) are useless but that's because I've put them in my general configuration to avoid linking them in each project I do.

Comment: See my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751640/undefined-reference-to-gxx-personality-sj0) related question. This sort of issue is usually due to a library/ABI mismatch between your compiler and the compiler that was used to compile the library.

Comment: @Mankarse I understand, and in fact I noticed that the library was compiled with g++, while I'm using mingw32-g++ to compile the code.
However I can't figure out how to change the compiler that builds the library since it is using Scons and I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: Also I've just tried to compile/link my snippet with g++ ( which I used to build the library ) but the same error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this by importing into Code::Blocks the source code of JsonCpp and creating the library myself. I am still baffled though as to why the library created with Scons didn't work, since it was using the same compiler that Code::Blocks uses, but at the same time it was not ( or the error wouldn't have been there ).

Answer (score 45):

For those coming to this from google (like i did), the real cause of the undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume` and `__gxx_personality_v0` is "using a gcc that uses a different stack unwinding method than dwarf2" [[1](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/603070/850244#target)]

In my case it was attempting to link code compiled with GCC 4.9 upwards with a library compiled with GCC 4.8 or below.  The solution is to recompile the library with the same compiler you're building with.

Comment: Good answer.  I ran into the `__Unwind_Resume` error when I was trying to revert to gcc 3 after using gcc 4.  I had to go back and recompile two libraries with gcc 3 before I could link them.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered that same problem attempting to use g++ -g -std=c++17 ... . I removed that option and, once I had removed use of a C++17 feature, it compiled, linked and ran.