# Undefined reference to _unwind_resume when using Google test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, gcc, codeblocks, mingw32

I set up Google test for some test driven development on my desktop PC and all went well. Now I'm away from home, I have downloaded my code and set up google test in the same way on my laptop and all is not well. Google test compiles fine, but I get "undefined reference to _unwind_resume" messages when compiling my tests.

Both my Desktop and laptop are running Windows 7 with the latest MinGW and I followed the same steps set it up. I am using Code::Blocks to compile the tests.

This is what I have used to compile the Google test and mock libraries:

> g++ -IC:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\gtest/include -IC:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\gtest -IC:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0/include -IC:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0 -c C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\gtest/src/gtest-all.cc
>
> g++ -IC:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\gtest/include -IC:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\gtest -IC:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0/include -IC:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0 -c C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0/src/gmock-all.cc
>
> ar -rv libgmock.a gtest-all.o gmock-all.o

This goes well and provides a libgmock.a file. That is then linked in the compiler settings in Code::Blocks and the correct include directories are specified too.

Building the tests in Code::Blocks gives these errors:

> C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to`_Unwind_Resume'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x2d7): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x3d5): undefined reference to`_Unwind_Resume'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x499): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x7d6): more undefined references to`_Unwind_Resume' follow
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZNK7testing8internal6StringcvSsEv+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZN7testing8internal6StringaSEPKc+0x13): undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZN7testing8internal8FilePathC1EPKc+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZN7testing8internal8FilePathC1ERKNS0_6StringE+0x13): undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZN7testing7MessageC1Ev+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
>   C:\Codes\programs\gmock-1.6.0\libgmock.a(gtest-all.o):gtest-all.cc:(.eh_frame$_ZN7testing7MessageC1ERKS0_+0x13): more undefined references to`__gxx_personality_v0' follow

Compiler flags in Code::Blocks include -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11

I can't work out what I've done differently to before and I'm a bit stuck.

---

## SOLUTION

The solution to my problem was that Code::Blocks apparently uses it's own MinGW. To fix, I went to compiler settings >> Toolchain executables and changed the install directory to where I installed the correct version of MinGW.

Comment: I suggest you look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22774664/1111557

Comment: I did see that. I'm using the same compiler to compile both the Google test library and my tests (gcc 4.8.1) and I thought it used dwarf2 by default.