# ld undefined reference to symbol '_Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0' C++17

Tags: gcc, c++17, clang

I have a program that I'm trying to compile that depends on C++17 features, during linking I get the following error.

```
ld -o exe bin/main.o bin/AssetHandle.o bin/Font.o bin/FramerateLimiter.o bin/Image.o bin/PhysicalDeviceInfo.o bin/Renderer.o bin/ShaderCompiler.o bin/StaticMesh.o bin/StaticRenderable.o bin/Utilities.o bin/Pipeline_Pipeline.o bin/Pipeline_AnimatedMeshPipeline.o bin/Pipeline_DebugWirePipeline.o bin/Pipeline_StaticMeshPipeline.o bin/Controllers_ControllerReader.o bin/Controllers_HidHelpers.o bin/Controllers_HidPs4.o bin/Controllers_HidXbone.o -L ~/C/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXrandr -lXi -lFreeImage -lhidapi-hidraw -lhidapi-libusb -ludev  -lc -lm
ld: bin/main.o: undefined reference to symbol '_Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0'
ld: /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
make: *** [Makefile:30: exe] Error 1
```

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419801/undefined-reference-to-unwind-resume-and-gxx-personality-v0) that says they were able to fix the problem by removing c++17 features but I can't easily try that with this project. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

This happens when compiled with either g++ or clang++

clang version 14.0.0 (Fedora 14.0.0-1.fc36)

gcc version 12.1.1 20220507 (Red Hat 12.1.1-1) (GCC)

GNU ld version 2.37-27.fc36

Comment: Did you install gcc or clang from sources?

Comment: no, from package manager. not even sure how to install from sources

Comment: Are you linking against third party libraries?

Comment: yes, quite a few of them installed from vcpkg and they depend on c++17

Comment: Oh you are using ld directly. Don't. If your compiler command is gcc 
then your linker command is also gcc.

Comment: could you show me how? simply changing ld to gcc creates so many errors that I can't even put it on pastebin

Comment: "creates so many errors" This should not happen. Please show the first few lines.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/qduiLNFn

Comment: You have to link C++ code compiled with gcc tooling using `g++`, always `g++` and only `g++` as the linker. Never `gcc` or `ld`

Comment: this is good to know, does the same apply for clang++?

Comment: Yes. The C++ compiler knows where different parts of its standard/runtime library are, and will add them to the ld arguments as required. Same goes for the C compiler. _Unwind_Resume is a part of gcc runtime library. You actually can do it yourself manually if you really need to, but why bother and introduce another source of potential errors?