Why g++ on windows using with cmake has this error
Maybe like this question, but I don't really solve it:
problem with g++ and "undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'"
I'm tring to test my program between clang and gcc, and I tried it on vscode with cmake changing the compiler and others.
But I encounter a error in vscode which I can't understand in my level.
[main] Building folder: F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 code_for_algo
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: F:\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE --build "F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32" --parallel 14 --target code_for_algo --
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/src/exp/explicit/explicit.cpp.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable code_for_algo.exe
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `show(Dog)':
[build] F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/src/exp/explicit/explicit.cpp:22:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `main':
[build] F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/src/exp/explicit/explicit.cpp:33:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `std::__throw_format_error(char const*)':
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/format:195:(.text$_ZSt20__throw_format_errorPKc[_ZSt20__throw_format_errorPKc]+0x5a): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `std::vformat[abi:cxx11](std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::basic_format_args<std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char> >)':
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/format:4254:(.text$_ZSt7vformatB5cxx11St17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEESt17basic_format_argsISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE[_ZSt7vformatB5cxx11St17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEESt17basic_format_argsISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE]+0x1bd): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:558:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ERKS4_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ERKS4_]+0xca): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj):C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:655: more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir\build.make:99: code_for_algo.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:123: code_for_algo] Error 2
[proc] The command: F:\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE --build "F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32" --parallel 14 --target code_for_algo -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:04.523
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
[main] Failed to prepare executable target with name "undefined"


But there is not error in I run it without using the ld.exe
just
g++ explicit.cpp -o my.exe -std=c++23 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo\src\exp\explicit>my.exe
Dog:
        Name:Normal Dog
        age: 0

Here is my program below:(just one file)
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

#define GET_NAME(x) #x

class Dog
{
  public:
    Dog() : m_name("Normal Dog"), m_age(0)
    {
    }
    Dog(int age) : m_age(age), m_name("Has Age Dog")
    {
    }
    std::string m_name;
    int m_age;
};

void show(Dog dog) 
{
    std::cout<<std::format( "Dog:\n\tName:{0}\n\tage: {1}\n", dog.m_name, dog.m_age);
}
// void print(auto var)
// {
//     std::print(std::cout, "Name: {0}\tType: {1}\n",GET_NAME(var),typeid(var).name());
// }
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Dog dog;
    show(dog);
    return 0;
}

info:
platform: windows 10
compiler and others:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
LD=/d/Prog/winlibs64ucrt_stage/custombuilt/share/binutils/bin/ld.exe
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders, r1)      


If there are C++ master could tell me what happend and how to fix it, very appreciate!
EDIT:
Thanks for hints from comments.
There are my CMakeLists.txt and CMakePreset.json files:
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)


project(code_for_algo VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

file(GLOB_RECURSE EXPLICIT_TEST src/exp/explicit/explicit.cpp)

set(CURRENT_SRC ${EXPLICIT_TEST})
message("CURRENT_SRC: \n" ${CURRENT_SRC})

add_executable(code_for_algo ${CURRENT_SRC})


CMakePreset.json:
{
    "version": 8,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "Clang",
            "displayName": "Clang",
            "hidden": true,
            "generator": "Ninja",
            "description": "Using compilers: C = F:\\LLVM\\llvm_19.1.0\\LLVM\\bin\\clang.exe, CXX = F:\\LLVM\\llvm_19.1.0\\LLVM\\bin\\clang++.exe",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
                "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "F:/LLVM/llvm_19.1.0/LLVM/bin/clang.exe",
                "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "F:/LLVM/llvm_19.1.0/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Clang_Debug",
            "displayName": "Clang_Debug",
            "inherits": "Clang",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Clang_Release",
            "displayName": "Clang_Release",
            "inherits": "Clang",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32",
            "displayName": "GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32",
            "description": "Using compilers: C = C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe, CXX = C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "generator": "MinGW Makefiles",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
                "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
                "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
            }
        }
    ]
}

And there are the cmake --verbose build info:
[main] Building folder: F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 code_for_algo
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: F:\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE --build "F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32" --parallel 14 --target code_for_algo --
[build] Change Dir: 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] 
[build] Run Build Command(s): F:/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E env VERBOSE=1 C:/PROGRA~1/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile -j14 code_for_algo
[build] F:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -SF:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo -B"F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo\out\build\GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32" --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
[build] C:/PROGRA~1/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 code_for_algo
[build] mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] F:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -SF:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo -B"F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo\out\build\GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32" --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
[build] F:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start "F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo\out\build\GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32\CMakeFiles" 2
[build] C:/PROGRA~1/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/all
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] C:/PROGRA~1/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/depend
[build] mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] F:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo "F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo\out\build\GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32" "F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo\out\build\GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32" "F:\dev\VS\cpp\code_for_algo\out\build\GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32\CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir\DependInfo.cmake" "--color="
[build] Dependencies file "CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/src/exp/explicit/explicit.cpp.obj.d" is newer than depends file "F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32/CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/compiler_depend.internal".
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target code_for_algo
[build] mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] C:/PROGRA~1/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/build
[build] mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] [ 50%] Linking CXX executable code_for_algo.exe
[build] F:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
[build] F:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E rm -f CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a
[build] C:\PROGRA~1\mingw64\bin\ar.exe qc CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir\objects1.rsp
[build] C:\PROGRA~1\mingw64\bin\G__~1.EXE -g -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o code_for_algo.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcode_for_algo.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir\linkLibs.rsp
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `show(Dog)':
[build] F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/src/exp/explicit/explicit.cpp:22:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `main':
[build] F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/src/exp/explicit/explicit.cpp:33:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `std::__throw_format_error(char const*)':
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/format:195:(.text$_ZSt20__throw_format_errorPKc[_ZSt20__throw_format_errorPKc]+0x5a): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `std::vformat[abi:cxx11](std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::basic_format_args<std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char> >)':
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/format:4254:(.text$_ZSt7vformatB5cxx11St17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEESt17basic_format_argsISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE[_ZSt7vformatB5cxx11St17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEESt17basic_format_argsISt20basic_format_contextINSt8__format10_Sink_iterIcEEcEE]+0x1bd): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj): in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:558:(.text$_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ERKS4_[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ERKS4_]+0xca): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[build] C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir/objects.a(explicit.cpp.obj):C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:655: more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\code_for_algo.dir\build.make:101: code_for_algo.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:92: CMakeFiles/code_for_algo.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32'
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:126: code_for_algo] Error 2
[build] 
[proc] The command: F:\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE --build "F:/dev/VS/cpp/code_for_algo/out/build/GCC 14.2.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32" --parallel 14 --target code_for_algo -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:02.243
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
[main] Failed to prepare executable target with name "undefined"


I also think this is an error about standard libs.

You should probably show your cmake file rather than your code.

not a c++ master, but it is a link error, you should look at your options for compile and link
https://stackoverflow.com/q/10419801/428494

First, you can run cmake build in verbose mode so it will output the exact command line it is invoking (--verbose should work with recent cmake). From the error it seems it has incompatible libraries, e.g. libstdc++ implementation not matching headers - it says x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh in version string - this can be a clue to check. and it says it is from objects.a - you can delete it and make it recompile just in case

You should use the linker that comes with your compiler
