# How do I set gcc to use the file extension (.c or .cpp) to determine the correct compiler/linker?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a simple, representative C program, stored in a file called `hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf('Hello, world\n');
    return 0;
}
```

On my Linux machine, I attempted to compile the program with gcc:

```
gcc hello.c
```

which returns an error:

```
undefined reference to "___gxx_personality_v0" ... etc
```

As has [been](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203548/869912) [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6045809/869912) before in the context of C++, this problem arises in the linking stage, when gcc attempts to link C libraries to a C++ program, thus giving the error. In [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626030/869912), someone mentioned that the extension *does* matter, and that gcc requires the `.c` extension when compiling C files, and some other extension (e.g. `.cpp`) when compiling C++ files.

**Question:** How do I set gcc to use the file extension to determine which compiler to use, since gcc seems to be defaulting to C++ on my system? Specifying the language through the file extension alone doesn't seem to be enough. If I specify the language using the `-x` flag, gcc functions as expected.

```
gcc -x c hello.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you let `make` decide this.

GNU Make has built in implicit rules, which automatically pick the right compiler.

Try a Makefile with these contents:

```
all: some_file.o some_other_file.o
```

And then place a `some_file.cpp` and `some_other_file.c` in the same directory, and gnu make will automatically pick the correct compiler. The linker, you may still have to provide yourself. When mixing C and C++, it's usually easiest to link with g++, like so:

```
program.exe: some_file.o some_other_file.o
    g++ -o $@ @^
```

This is the same as:

```
program.exe: some_file.o some_other_file.o
    g++ -o program.exe some_file.o some_other_file.o
```

Comment: Didn't see your edit before I posted my last comment (which dealt with make's implicit rules). I don't plan to mix C and C++ in this project, but this is still helpful to know.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano, I thought about 1 million SO users were going to answer this so I rushed to put up a place holder. :-)

Comment: Yikes, that obvious? Clearly C is not my specialty.