# Linking C++ on Rust: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)' and `__gxx_personality_v0', libstdc++ missing?

Tags: cmake, rust

I'm trying to build a cpp cmake project and link to my Rust project.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(ZLMediaKit_LIB CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

set(ENABLE_TESTS OFF FORCE)
option(ENABLE_TESTS OFF)

set(ENABLE_OPENSSL FALSE FORCE)
option(ENABLE_OPENSSL OFF)

add_subdirectory(ZLMediaKit)

add_library(libzlmediakit_cpp_interface STATIC interface.cpp)
target_include_directories(libzlmediakit_cpp_interface PUBLIC 
. 
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ZLMediaKit/src 
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ZLMediaKit/3rdpart/ZLToolKit/src)
target_link_libraries(libzlmediakit_cpp_interface zlmediakit zltoolkit mpeg mov flv libstdc++)
install(TARGETS libzlmediakit_cpp_interface DESTINATION .)
```

Here's my `build.rs`:

```
extern crate cmake;
use cmake::Config;

fn main()
{
    let dst = Config::new("zlmediakit_lib").build();       

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=libzlmediakit_cpp_interface");    
}
```

But I'm getting undefined reference errors:

```
ong)':
          /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:128: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/zlmediakit_rust/target/debug/build/zlmediakit_rust-499cc82f14515635/out/liblibzlmediakit_cpp_interface.a(interface.cpp.o): in function `ZLRTSPClient::~ZLRTSPClient()':
          /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/zlmediakit_rust/zlmediakit_lib/ZLRTSPClient.h:14: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/zlmediakit_rust/target/debug/build/zlmediakit_rust-499cc82f14515635/out/liblibzlmediakit_cpp_interface.a(interface.cpp.o): in function `std::default_delete<ZLRTSPClient>::operator()(ZLRTSPClient*) const':
          /usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:81: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/zlmediakit_rust/target/debug/build/zlmediakit_rust-499cc82f14515635/out/liblibzlmediakit_cpp_interface.a(interface.cpp.o): in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
          /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
          /usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/zlmediakit_rust/target/debug/build/zlmediakit_rust-499cc82f14515635/out/liblibzlmediakit_cpp_interface.a(interface.cpp.o):(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've researched and found some answers ([Link error "undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'" and g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045809/link-error-undefined-reference-to-gxx-personality-v0-and-g)) that old me to link against `libstdc++`. As you see, I'm already doing that.

If I try to compile the CMake project alone, it links sucessfully. However then I compile everything from the Rust side, it gives this error.

[Complete output of rust compilation](https://pastebin.com/Vza1dv3r)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still interested in this, it seems that you can fix it by doing to following:

1. You can add this to `Cargo.toml`:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
```

However, if you do this, your library is basically unusable as a normal rust dependency, as this only produces a static C library (you can still run tests though :O). However, you shouldn't need to do this for `bin` crates (probably?).

If you actually want this to be a library, you have to somehow find the path to `libstdc++.a` and link it in the `build.rs` file by using `println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=PATH_TO_LIB");`.

You can get the path by running `g++ --print-file-name=libstdc++.a`, but of course you can't hard-code it into `build.rs` since it will be different on different systems.

2. Then, you have two options:

- Add `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=stdc++");` to `build.rs` (ideally before the other `print` statements).
- Run the build command as `RUSTFLAGS="-C link-args=-lstdc++" cargo build`.

Long story short, the statically linked library produced by cmake does not actually contain the `stdc++` code, so we have to explicitly tell Rust where to go look for it.

If anyone has more insight into `cmake` and `cargo`, feel free to chime in and explain why this is necessary. As for me, I'm just glad it works.