# asserting std::holds_alternative with complex type fails to compile

Tags: c++, c++17

The following code uses `assert` to check if a `std::variant` holds some specific type, i.e. a complex type. However, it fails to compile with gcc-10, clang-7, and clang-14.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <list>
#include <variant>

template <typename K, typename V>
class Foo {
public:
    struct Item;

    using List = std::list<Item>;

    using Var = std::variant<V, typename List::iterator>;

    struct Item {
        K k;
        Var var;
    };
};

template <typename K, typename V>
class Bar {
public:
    auto func(typename Foo<K, V>::Var &var)
        -> typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator {

        assert(std::holds_alternative<typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator>(var));

        return std::get<typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator>(var);
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int, int>::Item item;
    Bar<int, int> bar;
    bar.func(item.var);
    return 0;
}
```

The compilers complain that assert is not declared:

```
t.cpp:25:55: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
        assert(std::holds_alternative<typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator>(var));
                                                      ^
/usr/include/assert.h:92:11: note: macro 'assert' defined here
#  define assert(expr)                                                  \
          ^
t.cpp:25:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'assert'; did you mean '__assert'?
        assert(std::holds_alternative<typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator>(var));
        ^~~~~~
        __assert
/usr/include/assert.h:81:13: note: '__assert' declared here
extern void __assert (const char *__assertion, const char *__file, int __line)
            ^
t.cpp:25:9: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        assert(std::holds_alternative<typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator>(var));
        ^~~~~~
t.cpp:25:9: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        assert(std::holds_alternative<typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator>(var));
        ^~~~~~
t.cpp:36:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'Bar<int, int>::func' requested here
    bar.func(item.var);
        ^
2 warnings and 2 errors generated.
```

However, if I change the `assert` call to the following:

```
using Iter = typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator;

assert(std::holds_alternative<Iter>(var));
```

gcc-10 compiles successfully, while clang-7 and clang-14 fails with some strange error messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t-ce3ab8.o: in function `__clang_call_terminate':
t.cpp:(.text.__clang_call_terminate[__clang_call_terminate]+0x2): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: t.cpp:(.text.__clang_call_terminate[__clang_call_terminate]+0x7): undefined reference to `std::terminate()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t-ce3ab8.o: in function `std::__throw_bad_variant_access(char const*)':
t.cpp:(.text._ZSt26__throw_bad_variant_accessPKc[_ZSt26__throw_bad_variant_accessPKc]+0x12): undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
/usr/bin/ld: t.cpp:(.text._ZSt26__throw_bad_variant_accessPKc[_ZSt26__throw_bad_variant_accessPKc]+0x39): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t-ce3ab8.o: in function `std::bad_variant_access::~bad_variant_access()':
t.cpp:(.text._ZNSt18bad_variant_accessD2Ev[_ZNSt18bad_variant_accessD2Ev]+0x11): undefined reference to `std::exception::~exception()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t-ce3ab8.o: in function `std::exception::exception()':
t.cpp:(.text._ZNSt9exceptionC2Ev[_ZNSt9exceptionC2Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for std::exception'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t-ce3ab8.o: in function `std::bad_variant_access::~bad_variant_access()':
t.cpp:(.text._ZNSt18bad_variant_accessD0Ev[_ZNSt18bad_variant_accessD0Ev]+0x1e): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t-ce3ab8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTISt18bad_variant_access[_ZTISt18bad_variant_access]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t-ce3ab8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTISt18bad_variant_access[_ZTISt18bad_variant_access]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::exception'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/t-ce3ab8.o:(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any portable solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros have some pitfalls, not only for the writer of the macro, but also for the user. `,` is special, because it delimits parameters to function like macros, hence can cause issues when it appears in the parameters. Here, adding brackets helps:

```
assert((std::holds_alternative<typename Foo<K, V>::List::iterator>(var)));
    // ^                                                               ^
```

Comment: Great! This solves the original problem. However, why the solution I proposed makes clang complain some strange error?

Comment: @for_stack cannot reproduce it https://godbolt.org/z/vM6a9WsTG

Comment: It's strange. I run the code in 3 docker containers, one installs gcc-10, one installs clang-10, and the other installs clang-14. Gcc works while clang fails, even with your solution.

Comment: @for_stack I can get it to compile also with clang https://godbolt.org/z/vaE9r9fnn. Perhaps try to reproduce it in godbolt.

Comment: @for_stack The linker errors you're seeing with `clang` are possibly due to `clang` linking with `libc++` by default.  You might want to try adding `-stdlib=libstdc++` to your link command.  Just a guess though.

Comment: @G.M. points out the problem and solution. I also googled [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045809/link-error-undefined-reference-to-gxx-personality-v0-and-g). Looks like my clang is not installed correctly. Still not sure why it fails in this case, while it can compile other code correctly. Anyway, thanks guys!