# Compiling with g++ but still giving error " undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0 "

Tags: c++, parallax, stamp

I`m trying to run basic stamp from ubuntu . I downloaded bstamp.sourceforge.net . I tried changing the makefile using gcc with -lstdc++ and also g++ .
Please suggest a fix .Stuck for HOURS .
THe source code for bstamp_tokenize.cpp is here : http://pastebin.com/Q9f1m2iG 
THe source code for bstamp_run is here : http://pastebin.com/KLEf8SBF

This is the error I`m getting :

```
**main_server@main-server:~/Desktop/bstamp$ bstamp_tokenize robot.bs2 robot.tok
/usr/local/lib/libbstamptokenizer.so: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0: Success
./tokenizer.so: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0: Success**
```

Comment: I suspect you should be using `g++` as your final linking stage as well as during the compile of the source.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined Symbol \_\_\_gxx\_personality\_v0 on link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203548/undefined-symbol-gxx-personality-v0-on-link)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `-lgnustl_static` in your compilation line in order to make it run.