# ld returned 1 exit status linker error

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to implement a simple c++ program which takes an input string with punctuation characters and return an output string removing those punctuations. The program is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int index=0;
   string sequence1,sequence2;
   cout<<"enter the sequence"<<endl;
   getline(cin,sequence1);
   for(index=0;index<20;++index)
      if(!ispunct(sequence1[index]))
         sequence2[index]=sequence1[index];
   cout<<sequence2<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

It gives me an error saying `ld returned 1 exit status`.The total error is

```
progprac: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
progprac: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
progprac:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
progprac: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
progprac: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
progprac: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccpOfw2A.o: In function `main':
progprac.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
progprac:(.text+0xe4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
progprac:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in progprac(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked online that it is a linker error where you declare a function and not define it. But I haven't made such an error. What is the error?

Comment: Your code compiles fine: [link](http://ideone.com/bFgBSA).

Comment: Please include the complete linker error message

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined Symbol \_\_\_gxx\_personality\_v0 on link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203548/undefined-symbol-gxx-personality-v0-on-link)

Comment: U used g++ for compiling?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I still can't compile my code. Is it my compiler problem?

Comment: @talasila It's not compiler problem. It's problem of the build system. Can you specify how you are trying to build your source file?

Comment: @talasila  How are you compiling and running it? What are you entering on the terminal (if you are using it)?

Comment: @SuVP I am running using this command .g++ progprac progprac.cc

Comment: @talasila  `g++ -o progprac progprac.cc`? or alternatively `g++ progprac.cc` to create an executable `a.out`

Comment: oh ya...very silly mistake. I overlooked -o in the command. Now it's compiling. I am sorry. Just another question. Is my cout statement at end of program wrong. It is compiling fine but the output is not shown. cout<<sequence2<<endl is not being displayed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `-o` in compile line,

```
g++ -o progprac progprac.cc
```

**After resolving 1st problem,**

You have created a blank string `sequence2` and in your `for` loop you make a `if` check to assign value to `sequence2` and you use `index` as a subscript for it. In some cases, (where there are punctuation marks you don't assign anything to that character position of `sequence2`). That can be a source of trouble as the string is still `""` .

If you use `sequence2.at(index)` it says `out of range`, which means the string does not exist[no characters] at those locations.

If you use `+` operator, you eliminate those issues, because you concatenate the characters to your existing string (starting with `""`)

```
         sequence2 += sequence1[index];
```