# C++ Map Initialization throws .text Error

Tags: c++, dictionary, constructor, maps, std

I'm having a weird error. I'm trying to use the Map library, and doing so is breaking my code.

I define my map thusly:

```
map<int, int> myMap;
```

And that breaks my code. If I comment it out, everything runs as expected. My code isn't super complicated or doing anything weird either.

The exact error is:

```
/tmp/ccapuHUe.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int>>>::decallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int>>*, unsigned int)`:
program.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKiiEEE10deallocateEPS5_j[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int>>>::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int>>*, unsigned int)]+0xd: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)`
/tmp/ccapuHue.0:(.eh_frame+0x4b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0`
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what any of that means. I'm not even using other map functions, just the initialization *(I'll add the other functions once I sort this out)*.

My gcc is version 4.3.6, if that matters.

Just to be ***certain***, I tested the following code:

```
#include <map>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::map<int, int> myMap;
    return 0;
}
```

And that doesn't work either! I get the same error *(Aside from the .text location)*!

Am I doing something wrong? The [Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/) for C++ Map Constructors show that this is a valid construct. Is something wrong with my computer or something?

Comment: Does this happen when compiling with gcc instead of g++, or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: I don't get it... g++ worked, gcc didn't. Why?

Comment: @Boom: gcc is a C compiler (and linker), so it won't link with the C++ library. Use a C++ compiler like g++ for C++.

Comment: [This seems pretty similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203548/undefined-symbol-gxx-personality-v0-on-link?lq=1)

Comment: I've never had this problem before. How strange. I'll flag this as a duplicate linking the other question.